# Getting different imeis using the imei_plugin package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, imei

I use the imei plugin package to get the phone's imei, but it gives me a new code every time. Why does this happen?

code:

`imei = await ImeiPlugin.getImei();`

`List<String> multiImei = await ImeiPlugin.getImeiMulti();`

output:

> 56f29767-c31c-45f9-95e9-dbacf714c417‏

> 1755d2f9-5640-4297-b57f-fa0fdd1434b5‏

Answer (score 0):

Do You run it on a simulator ?
If the answer is yes so check the setting for that .

Comment: Not
I tried it on my real phone